# running gstreamer pipeline command from opencv videowriter api to stream continuous image to hlssink

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, http-live-streaming, hlsl

I'm trying to stream continuos image from video card device using opencv videowriter api , below is the opencv code snippet which does the action, my problem is that i am getting the frame but not getting any index.m3u8 file generated inside /var/www folder i am new to opencv and gstreamer couldn't able to figure is this possible to achieve from opencv or i have to use some other mechanism

> input video device is a video card which supports only MJEPG codec

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0')
framerate = 30.0

out = cv2.VideoWriter('appsrc ! image/jpeg ! '
                      'jpegdec ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! '
                      'mpegtsmux ! hlssink location=/var/www/segment-%05d.ts '
                      'playlist-location=/var/www/index.m3u8 max-files=20 target-duration=15',
                      0, framerate, (640, 480))

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        out.write(frame)
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCv's `VideoWriter` only supports BGR frames on its GStreamer interface. Probably `VideoCapture` will also convert image to BGR.

So you don't need to decode jpeg in your gstreamer pipeline. However `x264enc` does not always accept BGR as input, so you should add `videoconvert` between `appsrc` and x264enc`

```
t = cv2.VideoWriter('appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! '
                      'mpegtsmux ! hlssink location=/var/www/segment-%05d.ts '
                      'playlist-location=/var/www/index.m3u8 max-files=20 target-duration=15',
                      0, framerate, (640, 480))
```