# Opencv save last N seconds of a camera stream

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-encoding

Is there a way to save last N seconds of a video stream to a file with openCV? E.g. The camera recording starts at 0s and ends at 20s leading to a recorded file which contains the video from 10s -> 20s.

One way I can think of is to save last N seconds in a memory buffer and write them to file once the process finishes, but this is not a desireable solution because of the latency involved at the end as well as memory limitations when multiple HD streams are involved.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. present your research. show effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution, in case anyone needs it.

```
t = cv2.VideoWriter('appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! '
                  'mpegtsmux ! hlssink location=/var/www/segment-%05d.ts '
                  'playlist-location=/var/www/index.m3u8 max-files=20 target-duration=15',
                  0, framerate, (640, 480))
```

Essentially you create a gstreamer pipline with opencv and control the target-duration property to achieve the desired result.

Here is a [Link to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61422014/running-gstreamer-pipeline-command-from-opencv-videowriter-api-to-stream-continu)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use a fifo buffer for the last 10 seconds or stream and past it into a file when the process stop (as you've explained).

why would it imply a latency though ? just need to use 2 buffer.
a short buffer for display and long fifo buffer for recording last 10 sec

Comment: Writing (encoding) 10x60 frames will take significant time

Comment: you have to save 60 frames per sec, it seems doable    
  
plus there are encoder like libx265 to get high quality image with light data packets

Answer (score 1):

Common "dashcam"/CCTV solutions write short video segments continuously, then remove the oldest ones as needed.

You can't have a single file in which data "disappears" again.

Use streamable video container formats like MPEG (1/2) Transport Streams (`.ts` or `.mts` or various other suffixes). These types can be decoded even if they're incomplete. Do not use containers that must be "finalized" (metadata written) to be decodable, e.g. `.mp4`. In any exceptional situation, incomplete files of that type would be unrecoverable.